# Visualising Cluster Shape for Clusters Generated by Fuzzy C Means Clustering

Tags: python, visualization, contour, fuzzy, fuzzy-c-means

I am trying to plot a visualization for the clusters obtained from Fuzzy C-Means clustering algorithm. I want to plot the contours along with the data points as shown in the following figure using Python. [image]

How do I proceed with this?